# How to print all word documents in a folder without opening them?

Tags: c#, ms-word

How can I programmatically in C# print page 7 and 8 of all word documents in a certain folder without opening them all?
The question is not how to looping through the documents, my difficulty lies in not to having to open them.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to read text from a file in code without code "opening" the file. It has to open the file in order to be able to read the file, and that's the only way you'd be able to have code print pages 7 & 8 from those files.

Comment: `my difficulty lies in not to having to open them.` Why specifically do you want to not open them?

Comment: because when I have 200 or more documents it probably will take hours

Comment: So are you trying to avoid _manually_ opening them? Is it OK to open them in an _automated_ way?

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through the documents in the folder, opening them one at a time with screen updating turned off, print, close without saving, and go to the next document. That should take no more time than simply printing but Word will not be available for use while it is running.

- If you do this, keep the instance of Word open while cycling through the documents. Do not open a new instance each time.